# Update object array key with new value in javascript/React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following Object array stored using `AsyncStorage`:

```
[
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a",
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ab",
  },
  {
    "groupId": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "abc",
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "name": "abcd",
  },
]
```

I'm retrieving the data to display it in a Flatlist but instead of displaying the `groupId`, I would like to display the `groupName` for each item.

I have another key with groups stored:

```
[
 {
  "groupName": "g1",
  "id": 1,
 },
 {
  "groupName": "g2",
  "id": 2,
 }
]
```

I made a function to retrieve the `groupName` based on `groupId`. This works fine:

```
const getGroupName = async (groupIdToFind) => {
    const existingsGroups = (await AsyncStorage.getItem("groups")) || "[]"; 
    const existingsGroupsParsed = JSON.parse(existingsGroups);

    const groupDataFound = existingsGroupsParsed.find(
      (results) => results.id.toString().indexOf(groupIdToFind) > -1
    );

    if (groupDataFound) {
      return groupDataFound.groupName;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

And I thought of modifying the data retrieved from the storage in my `loadFlatlist` function but this is where I'm struggling.

```
const loadFlatlist = async (storageKey) => {
try {
  let itemsOnStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storageKey);

  itemsOnStorage = JSON.parse(itemsOnStorage);

  if (itemsOnStorage !== null) {
    let finalItemsOnStorage = "";
    itemsOnStorage.map(async function (obj) {
      console.log(obj.groupId);  // Correctly returns 1, 2, 3 ...

      let retrievedGroupName = await getGroupName(obj.groupId);
      console.log(retrievedGroupName);   // Correctly returns g1, g2 ...

      finalItemsOnStorage = await update(itemsOnStorage, {
        groupId: { $set: retrievedGroupName },
      });
    });

    console.log(finalItemsOnStorage);  // Returns same content as itemsOnStorage

    setDataOnDevice(itemsOnStorage);  // This will be loaded in my flatlist
  }
} catch (err) {
  alert(err);
}
  };
```

The problem is in `loadFlatlist`, I did not manage to replace the `groupId` by the `groupName`. `finalItemsOnStorage` has the same content as `itemsOnStorage`.

Can you see what is wrong with my function? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
const loadFlatlist = async (storageKey) => {
try {
  let itemsOnStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  itemsOnStorage = JSON.parse(itemsOnStorage);

  const existingsGroups = (await AsyncStorage.getItem("groups")) || "[]"; 
  const existingsGroupsParsed = JSON.parse(existingsGroups);

  if (itemsOnStorage !== null) {
    let finalItemsOnStorage = [];

    itemsOnStorage.forEach(item => {

       let index = existingsGroupsParsed.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 
     item.groupId)

            if(index != -1) {
                finalItemsOnStorage.push({...item,
                              groupId:existingsGroupsParsed[index].groupName})
                          }
                });

    console.log(finalItemsOnStorage);  

    setDataOnDevice(finalItemsOnStorage);   
  }
} catch (err) {
  alert(err);
}
  };
```

Comment: Glad to help :)